# AsyncLayoutInflator info?

Tags: android, android-layout

At the fireside chat at IO 2016 there was mention of an AsyncTaskLoader in the support library.  Where can this be found and is there any documentation available? Is there any same code demonstrating usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android.support.v4.view.AsyncLayoutInflater
```

Was added to the `24.0.0-alpha1` support v4 library, you can use this in your projects now.

```
new AsyncLayoutInflater(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_layout, null, new AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInflateFinished(View view, int resid, ViewGroup parent) {
            //Do something with view
        }});
```

I believe the documentation will be added to the N preview documentation.

You can check out a full diff for the support library [here](https://gist.github.com/MichaelEvans/5d7c55382198640345dc#file-support-v4-diff-L93)